# What could be shortest code for this -- is any possibility with switch Case?

Tags: java

The below code has many duplicate lines, looking for a short thing for this.

```
if(null!= commonShipmentSplInstr.getIsGiftOrder() && GIFT_ORDER_FLAG.equalsIgnoreCase(commonShipmentSplInstr.getIsGiftOrder())) {
    printObj.setDOCUMENT(INVOICE_DOCUMENT_FOR_PROSHIP_GIFT_ORDER);

    giftMessageLine1 = commonShipmentSplInstr.getGiftMessageLine1();
    giftMessageLine2 = commonShipmentSplInstr.getGiftMessageLine2();
    giftMessageLine3 = commonShipmentSplInstr.getGiftMessageLine3();
} else if(null!= commonShipmentSplInstr.getSplInstr6() && GIFT_ORDER_FLAG.equalsIgnoreCase(commonShipmentSplInstr.getSplInstr6())) {
    printObj.setDOCUMENT(INVOICE_DOCUMENT_FOR_PROSHIP_GIFT_ORDER);

    giftMessageLine1 = commonShipmentSplInstr.getGiftMessageLine1();
    giftMessageLine2 = commonShipmentSplInstr.getGiftMessageLine2();
    giftMessageLine3 = commonShipmentSplInstr.getGiftMessageLine3();
} else if (null != sellingChannel && InvoiceHelper.isZolaSellingChannel(sellingChannel)) {
    printObj.setDOCUMENT(INVOICE_DOCUMENT_FOR_PROSHIP_ZOLA_ORDER);
} else {
    printObj.setDOCUMENT(DOCUMENT_FOR_PRINT_INVOICE_LABEL_FOR_PROSHIP);
}
```

In the setDOCUMENT method, all are Constants.

Comment: Just extract your duplicate code in some private method and call it insde 1st and 2nd block.

Comment: You don't need the null checks in `null != a && b.equalsIgnoreCase(a)`.

Comment: Well, if you have methods like `getGiftMessageLine1()`, `getGiftMessageLine2()` and `getGiftMessageLine3()`, I would find that questionable in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just combine the two first if clause into one, they seem to be doing exactly the same:

```
if(commonShipmentSplInstr != null && (GIFT_ORDER_FLAG.equalsIgnoreCase(commonShipmentSplInstr.getIsGiftOrder()) || GIFT_ORDER_FLAG.equalsIgnoreCase(commonShipmentSplInstr.getSplInstr6()))) {
    printObj.setDOCUMENT(INVOICE_DOCUMENT_FOR_PROSHIP_GIFT_ORDER);

    giftMessageLine1 = commonShipmentSplInstr.getGiftMessageLine1();
    giftMessageLine2 = commonShipmentSplInstr.getGiftMessageLine2();
    giftMessageLine3 = commonShipmentSplInstr.getGiftMessageLine3();
}
else if (null != sellingChannel && InvoiceHelper.isZolaSellingChannel(sellingChannel)) {
    printObj.setDOCUMENT(INVOICE_DOCUMENT_FOR_PROSHIP_ZOLA_ORDER);
}
else {
    printObj.setDOCUMENT(DOCUMENT_FOR_PRINT_INVOICE_LABEL_FOR_PROSHIP);
}
```

Comment: The null-checks in the if clause are not needed because the equalIgnoreCase method will simply return false if the argument ist null, Its true but ---- getter inside that is giving NPE the isGift Order is null

Comment: Oops, I didn't see that. You're absolutely right.

Comment: I updated the answer, re-added the null check.

Comment: Still not done, commonShipmentSplInstr is a complex object which has many variables in which getIsGiftOrder for the time being its null. Checking null for commonShipmentSplInstr does not make sure that getIsGiftOrder is not null

Comment: But the equalsIgnoreCase does that null check.